# How to change the default color of the "joined" lines in BarChart function?

Tags: plotting, color, charts, style

is there any way to change the default color of the joined lines in BarChart function? As the joined function turns on (i.e., Joined -> True), the joined lines are plotted automatically with the colors of the bar chart. I want to use other colors to show these reference lines. Many thanks for your help!

Here is a toy example in the Mathematica manual.

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 5}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, BarSpacing -> 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: `BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 5}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  Joined -> True, BarSpacing -> 0.5] /. Line[a_] :> {Cyan, Line[a]}` ?

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you very much for your quick reply. Your solution works. But this code also changes the color of the x axis. Is there any way to prevent the color of the axis being changed simultaneously?

Comment: It's a fragile hack though. It would be strange if there really wasn't any way to change this (without hacks), yet I can't find a way.

Comment: another hack: `BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, 
  BarSpacing -> 0.5] /. Directive[p_PointSize, a_AbsoluteThickness, c_] :> Directive[p, a, Red]`

Comment: yet another: `BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, 
  BarSpacing -> 0.5] /.  Line[x_] /; Length[x] > 2 :> {Red, Line[x]}`

Comment: @kglr Many thanks again for your great help! It works exactly as what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
```

An alternative hack is to temporarily re-define `Darker` (which is used to style the joined lines) as the desired line color (say, `Red`):

```
Block[{Darker = (Red &)}, 
 BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, BarSpacing -> 0.5]]
```

[image]

To have different colors for each line, post-process to replace `Red` with desired colors:

```
linecolors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Magenta};

Block[{Darker = (Red &)}, 
 ReplaceAll[Red :> Last[linecolors = RotateLeft[linecolors]]]@
  BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, BarSpacing -> 0.5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];

bc = BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, BarSpacing -> 0.5]
```

[image]

Two post-processing hacks:

```
replaceAll1 = ReplaceAll[Directive[p_, a_, c_] :> Directive[p, a, Red]];

replaceAll2 = ReplaceAll[Line[x_] /; Length[x] > 2 :> {Red, Line @ x}];

replaceAll1 @ bc
```

[image]

```
replaceAll2 @ bc
```

> same picture

To have a different color for each line:

```
linecolors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Magenta};

replaceAll1b = ReplaceAll[Directive[p_, a_, c_] :> 
   Directive[p, a, Last[linecolors = RotateLeft[linecolors]]]]

replaceAll2b = ReplaceAll[Line[x_] /; Length[x] > 2 :> 
  {Last[linecolors = RotateLeft[linecolors]], Line @ x}];

replaceAll1b @ bc
```

[image]

```
replaceAll2b @ bc
```

> same picture

Alternatively, we can use composition of `Show` and `replaceAll1b` as the setting for the option `DisplayFunction`:

```
displayfunction1 = Show @* replaceAll1b;

BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, BarSpacing -> 0.5, 
   DisplayFunction -> displayfunction1]
```

[image]

Similarly, with `replaceAll2b`:

```
displayfunction2 = Show @* replaceAll2b;

BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, BarSpacing -> 0.5, 
   DisplayFunction -> displayfunction2]
```

> same picture